# Command to fetch column information

Tags: batch-file

I have a command `incmd version` which produces below output

```
All Rights Reserved.
This Software is protected by U.S. Patent Numbers 5,794,246; 6,014,670; 6,016,50
1; 6,029,178; 6,032,158; 6,035,307; 6,044,374; 6,092,086; 6,208,990; 6,339,775;
6,640,226; 6,789,096; 6,820,077; 6,823,373; 6,850,947; 6,895,471; 7,117,215; 7,1
62,643; 7,254,590; 7,281,001; 7,421,458; 7,496,588; 7,523,121; 7,584,422; 7,720,
842; 7,721,270; and 7,774,791, international Patents and other Patents Pending.

Version: 9.1.0 HotFix2
Build: 1668 - 2011-Sep-02
Command ran successfully.
```

I want to fetch `9.1.0` out of it. so far using `findstr "Version"` i only get `Version: 9.1.0 HotFix2` Is there a way I can extract column information?

**Note**: Without using any third party tools.. (anytool that is available by default in windows is fine)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` to tokenize that output:

```
for /f "tokens=2, delims= " %v in ('incmd version ^| findstr Version') do @set Version=%v
echo %Version%
```

See `help for` for a detailed explanation of the command and its options.

Note that if you are using this in a batch file (which I assumed at first, but apparently wasn't the case) you have to double the percent signs in the `for` variable:

```
for /f "tokens=2, delims= " %%v in ('incmd version ^| findstr Version') do @set Version=%%v
echo %Version%
```

Comment: it gives me `%%v is unexpected at this time.`

Comment: If you are using *within* a batch file, you must use `%%v`. If you are just testing from the command line, just use `%v`.